# How to solve this problem on probability?

Tags: probability

The probability of a man hitting a target is 3/4. He tries 5 times. What is the probability that the target will be hit at least 3 times ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have a look at the binomial distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. According to this [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function), the probability that after $5$ tries, the man hit the target exactly $k$ times is
$$\binom{5}{k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k}$$
where $p=3/4$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yeah got it! just need to sum up for 3,4 and 5

Comment: Yes. Well done!!

Comment: try [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296444/stationary-state-of-an-infinite-markov-chain)

Comment: @RobertZ,@vidyarthi..why are failures considered in binomial distribution?.. the (1-p) term!

Comment: @nrb Because for $5$ tries if we have $k$ successes ($p$ term) then there are also $5-k$ failures ($(1-p)$ term)

Comment: @RobertZ can i solve this problem using binomial distribution?..A bag contains 10 mangoes out of which 4 are rotten . Two mangoes are taken out together. If one of them is good then what is the probability that other is also good?

Comment: This is a conditional probability problem.  If you need help, it is better to ask it in another question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, though can be solved by using starightforward logic, is a case of [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), as the hittings to the target are independent Bernoullian trials with outcomes of a success with probability $=\frac3{4}$ and a failure with probability=$\frac1{4}$. Therefore, we have the required answer $$=\sum_{k=3}^5\binom{5}{k}(\frac1{4})^{5-k}(\frac3{4})^k$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect: the question states that the target should be hit at least three times.

Comment: @jvdhooft thanks, modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

So here we need to make an assumption that every hit of the man is **independent** (which is not always be the case in general - think that if he misses one, maybe next hit he had a big pressure, but here let's assume that hits are independent).

Then we could say how many scenario are there that he hit at least $3$ times?

Hit exactly 3 times:

$\binom{5}{3}$ cases,the probability for each of the case is always $\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}$ - thanks to the communicative property of multiplication. Thus we have $\binom{5}{3}(\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{1}{4})^3$

I'll leave the rest of the analysis to you, i.e. hit exactly 4 times, and hit exactly 5 times. And at then end, you want to add the three cases together.